# Custom GWT ListBox Widget

Tags: java, gwt, listbox, widget

I'm trying to create a custom GWT ListBox widget.  The items in my list have verbose text and terse text.  The verbose text, e.g., "The cat in the hat", display when the list box is open (expanded).  Once an item is selected, then the terse form of the text is displayed, e.g., "cat".

I'm using two GWT ListBoxes (one with the verbose strings and one with terse strings) and hiding one or the other through their onClick handlers.  My current issue is when I click the terse listbox and hold the click it displays all the terse strings when I want it to display the other listbox.

Any suggestions?

My code:

```
public class TerseVerboseListBox extends Composite implements ClickHandler {
    //implements ClickHandler, ChangeHandler, HasChangeHandlers {

    //onset OnsetListBox extends ListBox and accepts TerseVerboseItem as an argument to AddItem
    //TerseVerboseItem simply contains two strings, a terse one and a verbose one
   private OnsetListBox verboseListBox;
   private OnsetListBox terseListBox; 
   private AbsolutePanel absolutePanel;

   /**
    * Constructs a TerseVerboseListBox 
    * 
    */
 public TerseVerboseListBox() {
    absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
    terseListBox = new OnsetListBox();
    verboseListBox = new OnsetListBox();

    populateListBoxes();

    //replace verbose list box with terse listbox after item is selected
    verboseListBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
           int selectedIndex = verboseListBox.getSelectedIndex();               
           verboseListBox.setVisible(false);
           terseListBox.setVisible(true);
           terseListBox.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
         }
    });

    terseListBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onChange(final ChangeEvent event) {
           verboseListBox.setVisible(true);
           terseListBox.setVisible(false);
         }
    });

    terseListBox.setVisible(false);
    absolutePanel.add(verboseListBox);
    absolutePanel.add(terseListBox);

    // All composites must call initWidget() in their constructors.
    initWidget(absolutePanel);
    }

    private void populateListBoxes() {
        TerseVerboseItem tvItem = new TerseVerboseItem();
        tvItem.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        tvItem.setPosition(1);
        tvItem.setSeparator(false);
        tvItem.setTerseForm("<=");
        tvItem.setVerboseForm("Present by birth");

        TerseVerboseItem tvItem2 = new TerseVerboseItem();
        tvItem2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        tvItem2.setPosition(2);
        tvItem2.setSeparator(false);
        tvItem2.setTerseForm("@6M");
        tvItem2.setVerboseForm("Onset at 6 months");

        verboseListBox.addItem(tvItem);
        verboseListBox.addItem(tvItem2);
        terseListBox.addTerseItem(tvItem);
        terseListBox.addTerseItem(tvItem2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //maybe I should catch any clicks here
        //and determine which listbox is visible and show the other one
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: I added the code above